# Existence of first-order and higher-order bayesian probability

Tags: probability, logic, first-order-logic, bayesian, higher-order-logic

As normal Bayesian probability could be thought of as zeroth-order or propositional logic where the truth values are real numbers between 0 and 1 inclusive, do there exist Bayesian probability analogues of first-order and higher-order logic?

Comment: You may be interested in *fuzzy* and *continuous* first-order logic; I don't know to what extent the analogous higher-order notions have been studied, given that even classical second-order logic is already terrible in many ways.